# Cannot get variable from sql query in Node

Tags: mysql, node.js

Sorry, I read about handling async functions in order to get variable names from them but I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how to handle it.

```
    for(let j = 0; j < ga.length; j++) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM matches WHERE clh = '"+ga[j]+"'"
    const dbq = db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var gs1 = 0;
        var gs2 = 0;
        var pts1 = 0;
        var w1 = 0;
        var d1 = 0;
        var l1 = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            gs1 += result[i].gsh;
            gs2 += result[i].gsa;
            const r = mgs1(result[i].gsh, result[i].gsa);
            if (r == 3) w1 += 1;
            if (r == 1) d1 += 1;
            if (r == 0) l1 += 1;
            var gd1 = gs1 - gs2;
            var r1 = [result[i].clh, result.length, w1, d1, l1, gs1, gs2, gd1 ];
        }
        
        gs4.push(r1);
        
        if (gs4.length == 6) {
            return gs4;
        }
    })
}
}
```

This function returns the array that I want but I am not sure how to access it outside the db.query block. I read posts about handling variables from async functions but I just can't seem to do it in this example. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What lib are you using for nodejs integration with database?

Comment: hi, thanks for getting back! I am using const mysql = require('mysql'); I read answer here that standard 'db.connect' is buggy and should be omitted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087924/cannot-enqueue-handshake-after-invoking-quit so I left it out.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have defined `const gs4 = []` somewhere in code you did not show us. That's part of the answer to your question: it will be populated after your callback from `db.query()` completes.

The rest of the answer: it is *not* populated until after the callback completes. Also, the `return` from inside your callback is meaningless; it just returns to `db.query()` .

Also, `db.query()` returns to its caller instantly, long before it calls its callback. So your loop tries to run multiple queries concurrently. I guess the result in `gs4` will accumulate the results from all the queries.

With respect, I believe a quick jump up the learning curve for Promises or `async / await` lies in your near future.

This may help : [node.js mysql query in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020695/node-js-mysql-query-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to query the database the correct way, you should use the embedded functions that comes with database driver. For string interpolation and returning data for your functions.

```
   exports.lookupLogin = (req, res, next) => {
        let sql = 'SELECT e.employee_id, e.login, e.password FROM employee e WHERE e.login=?';
        postgres.client.query(sql, [req.body.login], (error, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ errors: ['Could not do login'] });
            }

            res.status(200).json(result.rows);
        });
    };
```

For more information you can check the [mysql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) to use with nodejs.

Comment: ok, this will be very useful in the future. Upvoted but it doesn't show. Thanks a lot!